# Brexit impact data and forecasts

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth

I am looking for some new studies (preferable from 2021) about the medium/long term impacts of Brexit, especially accounting for the TCA agreement. I know there are many papers about these topic, but most of them came out before the signature of the TCA. I am looking for some basic numbers as impact on the long term GDP,